# What is a good way to Merge 2 range sets into a single view

Tags: oracle

The real purpose of this has to do with effectivity dates and contains additional keys and fields, but I simplified it for the sake of, well, simplicity.

Sample:

```
test_Widget Table
theFirst   theLast    Letter
1          5          A
7          10         (null)
11         15         C

test_Default Table
theFirst   theLast    Letter
1          8          T
9          12         U
13         20         V

Expected Output:
theFirst   theLast    Letter
1          5          A
7          8          T
9          10         U
11         15         C
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Use the `Widget` and `Override` table to craft a query that has for every range of numbers the proper `Letter` chosen.

Use `Widget.Letter` for all Letters, but in the case of a NULL in `Widget` use the `Default.Letter`. Only include ranges that are inclusive to the `Widget` table

I have working code that does it, but I'm wondering if there's something a bit more elegant, built-in, etc to handle this.

My code:

```
select distinct
  case when w.letter is null then greatest(w.thefirst, d.thefirst) else w.thefirst end as tfirst, 
  case when w.letter is null then least(w.thelast, d.thelast) else w.thelast end as tlast,
  case when w.letter is null then d.letter else w.letter end as letter
from test_widget w
inner join test_default d
on 
w.thefirst <= d.thelast and
w.thelast >= d.thefirst
```